# Redirect URL Warning (like Firefox) equivalent for IE, Firefox, & Maxthon

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, redirection, url

Firefox has an option (Option | Advanced | General): Warn me when websites try to redirect or reload a page.  This isn't precisely the behavior I want (lots of pop-ups and slows things down) but it will do.

What is the equivalent setting / workaround / add-on for IE, Chrome, and Maxthon (I don't have Maxthon now but plan to try it again soon)?  Note: using Vista and XP, so IE9/8 as well as 10.

I've looked through dozens of responses here or elsewhere without finding an answer (although one person did say there was a way for IE and Chrome when answering a question regarding Firefox last year.)  The closest I could find was an obscure zone specific setting for meta refresh for IE but that is just the second half of the Firefox setting (i.e., (dis)allow periodic  refresh).

Thanks.